# Used mutate and lag, get negative values that want to turn into 0

Tags: r, dplyr

I used the following work on a column where I subtract a row's value by the row's value before it.

```
mutate(diff = v1 - lag(v1, default = first(v1)))
```

Sometimes the above code gives me negative values, I don't want this. What's a nice way to replace negative numbers by 0 that branches off from the above code?

Comment: `pmax(0, v1 - lag(v1, default = first(v1)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use

```
library(dplyr) 
df1 %>%
     mutate(diff = v1 - lag(v1, default = first(v1)),
            diff = replace(diff, diff < 0, 0))
```